# What prevented Duke Nukem from mutating in the Duke Nukem video games?

Tags: video-games, duke-nukem

I remember fighting and shooting everything as Duke spouted one liners he borrowed from Bruce Campbell. 
What prevented the dancing girls &  Duke Nukem from morphing during crisises that made him our last, crass hope for mankind?
  [image: Duke Nukem 3D]

Comment: If anything was needed to prevent mutation, I'd say it was an excess of testosterone and all-around awesomeness.

Comment: @Valorum Wait. WHAT? The other question is a dup of mine.

Comment: @MajorStackings - My answer to the other question answers this one. Duke = Too badass to mutate.

Comment: @Valorum you answered the dupe shame on you :P. this one was asked 1 year earlier

Comment: @Valorum Well, oops. You did that bass ackwards.

Comment: Yup, dupe hammer needs to go the other way... or merge maybe?

Comment: @Skooba - I don't think it's any great loss leaving this one as the dupe. There are only two questions about Duke-Nukem and they're both basically the same.

Comment: @Valorum True. Except for one thing. The dup is open and the original isn't.

Comment: @MajorStackings - Dupes are determined by answers, not questions.

Comment: Yeah, merge em.

Comment: I have to question how a dup of an existing question can be answered and the original question becomes the dup. Seriously.  It makes no sense. You should have answered mine and dup'd the dup.

Comment: If you want my two-pence worth, it's because he was *always outta gum*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *Duke Nukem Forever*, there is no mutation. The Aliens bring their pigs with them. In *Duke Nukem: Manhattan Project* there was this green mutation goo, that reduced your health. I'd say you need long exposure (especially being a big tough guy like the Duke) to the goo in order to mutate. As for "the chicks", we learn in *Forever* that the aliens require live women to breed their offspring, so it wouldn't make sense to mutate them.

Answer (score 9):

I asked the co-creator of Duke Nukem; George Broussard this question on [twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/georgeb3dr/status/527236519665618944).

His response is simply that Duke is too badass to mutate.

> Q : "I'm struggling to work out why Duke isn't mutated by his own GLOPP gun. Any ideas?"
>
> A : **"You can't mutate [a] bad motherf*cker.**